# Cannot download R

Tags: r

Really stupid issue, apologies in advance. I am trying to download R since yesterday since I had a clean install on my computer. I cannot seem to access the site. All other pages of CRAN work, but when I want to access https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/ I get the error:

```
Object not found!

 The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring 
 page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page 
 about   the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

cran.r-project.org
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
```

Since it has been nearly a day I was wondering if there is something I can do, or an alternative R mirror?

Edit: should specify that I had used www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ before posting here, which suggested that it is just me (which does not seem to be the case).
Thanks for the helpful replies.

Comment: Seems like that link is down, check this website: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Comment: Very weird - most of the CRAN webpage is down for me.

Comment: Duplicate question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272188/unable-to-access-to-cran-web-pages

Comment: @zx8754, yes that was the first thing I did, but it showed me "it is just you". Still does! And apologies for the duplicate question.

Comment: Closing this as no longer repro-able. Also @Dreica, If you face any such general issues, note that Stack Overflow is not the right place for that. You can always ask such questions in [chatrooms like this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public). Stack Overflow is for programming related issues only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to download it here:

https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/